# Where to define Rails app's version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, versioning

Is there any convention about how/where to specify application's version number?

For example, for the ruby gems `lib/mygem/version.rb` is the file generally used for that purpose.

My guess would be creating `config/version.rb` file like that:

```
module MySite
  VERSION = "0.0.4"

  # or in MySite::Application class
  # 
  # class Application
  #   VERSION = "0.0.4"
  # end
end
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6178378/1352240

Comment: You can do this as I answered earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23135266/2881964

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I will reply my own question, I was not able to find a better answer.

Since Rails application is basically `MySite::Application` I thought app's version should be accessed by `MySite::Application::VERSION` so create :

**config/initializers/version.rb**

```
module MySite
  class Application
    VERSION = "0.0.4"
  end
end
```

or `config/version.rb` and require this file from `config/application.rb`

Comment: + To go the config/version.rb route, rembmer to put `require File.expand_path('../version', __FILE__)` at the end of config/application.rb

Comment: This is a great idea, but I'm setting it in the `config/application.rb` file, as this file already declares the `MySite::Application` class. In the case you need to rename your app, you actually change only one place. Finally, setting the version from an initializer sounds weird to me.

Comment: Probably defining `MySite::VERSION`, directly on the module, would be more aligned to what we already do for gems.

Answer (score 8):

I add my own version to the Configuration class with an initializer:

**app_version.rb**

```
class Configuration
  class << self
    attr_accessor :app_version
  end
  @app_version = 0.72
end
```

Within the app, I can pull the version:

```
@app_version = Configuration.app_version
```

Not sure why you want to use the version, but I often use versioning so I can see if a particularly version of code is actually running. In that case, I need every code revision to be reflected as a new version, so I use the Git version on my code and often just display the first few characters of it since that is likely unique enough to identify it.

```
@git_version = `git show --pretty=%H`[0..39]
```

Comment: This is super cool. How do I call it from a view? I'm missing something.

Comment: `@version = \`git log --oneline | head -1\`` could work as well - does for me ;) As long as you're good with *nix commands sneaking into your code as this will not travel well in windoze-country :D

Comment: Or `\`git describe --always\``